# Как распарсить закомментированные строки в yaml?

Tags: python, yaml

```
import yaml
from yaml.loader import SafeLoader

with open('C:\\Project\\test.yml', 'r') as f:
    data = list(yaml.load_all(f, Loader=SafeLoader))
print(data)
```

**Файл test.yml:**

```
fruits: apple
date: 20210709
finalized: true
project:
# - service:
#     image:
#     - chegototam-api
- ddd: null
```

**print(data):**

```
[{'fruits': 'apple', 'date': '20210709', 'finalized': True, 'project': [{'ddd': None}]}]
```

Каким образом получить закомментированные строки?

Comment: Если средствами модуля yaml - то раскомментировать, потом парсить. Например, построчно прочитать файл, убирая все "# " в началах строк. Но не факт что что-то лишнее не раскомментируется (какие-то комментарии для людей, например).

Comment: Ну как обычный текстовый файл можете прочесть. А смысл этого действия вообще в чём?

Comment: @CrazyElf По логике, закомментированные строки это уже установленные проекты и их тоже надо учитывать) Благодарю.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PyYAML отбрасывает комментарии на очень низком уровне (in Scanner.scan_to_next_token). По [состоянию на 2020 год](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7255983/9753359) запрос функции о добавлении поддержки загрузки комментариев все еще откладывается.

Можно попробовать читать построчно и выбирать строки, которые начинаются с "#":

```
comments = []
with open("./text1.txt") as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        if line.startswith("#"):
            comments.append(line[1:].strip())

print(comments)
```

ouput:

```
['- service:', 'image:', '- chegototam-api']
```